# RSpec 2 doesn't seem to load any fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, fixtures

I'm trying to access fixture data in my RSpec tests but doesn't seem to load any.

spec_helper.rb

```
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/db/fixtures"
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
config.global_fixtures = :all
```

This is one of my fixtures:

```
cash:
  name: cash
  interest: 1
  term: <%= Time.now.to_s :db %>
```

Now a test is creating up a user which has a after_create callback:

```
ft = FundType.find_by_name("cash")
Fund.create(fund_type_id: ft.id, amount: 1000) <--- this is where the error occurs
```

Error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ft = FundType.find_by_name("cash")
puts ft
puts ft.id
```

Verify your fixtures are in the directory:

```
 ls -1 db/fixtures
```

Verify your configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/db/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.global_fixtures = :all
end
```

Credit to the page that was previously here:
http://www.etagwerker.com/2011/08/how-to-load-all-fixtures-testing-with-rspec-2-and-rails-3/

Verify your test database comes up correctly:

```
 rake db:test:prepare
```

Then look at the test database. Did the fixtures get loaded?

Comment: File exists, configuration is exactly the same. This is output of `puts FundType.all` -> `[]` so there are no records.

Comment: Can you try removing the ERB? So like this... term: "2012-04-01"  (Also look for quirks like odd spacing or tabs, or trailing whitespace, or files without read permission)

Comment: Edited to add rake db:test:prepare info - can you try it?

Comment: That's a broken link.